# Open modal dialog based condition in select drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm opening a modal dialog box on click of a button like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openModal">Click</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="openModal"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
//modal body
</div>
```

I would like to know whether is there any method with which one can open a modal dialog based on select drop down??Particuylarly using javascript/angular js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fully catch the question. But, do you need something like [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SBf7XFnJfvxLllK2lQfS?p=preview)?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal1.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h3>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal2.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h3>
    </div>
</script>

Select number of modal you'd like to open:
<select ng-model="form.selection">
  <option value="modal1">Modal 1</option>
  <option value="modal2">Modal 2</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

and

```
$scope.form = {
  selection: "modal1"
};

$scope.open = function (size) {

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: $scope.form.selection + '.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
  });
};
```

Comment: Need to open modal on change of select drop down.Not on click of a button

Comment: Solved by adding ng-change="open()" in <select> element

Comment: @UmutBenzer I am making the same function and it worked but my problem now is this example of yours has only one button, how about if i have several buttons for the same dropdown value? for example add, modify,delete? Thanks I am using angularjs btw